# Swift blog or podcast

Tags: xcode, swift

I am new to swift and still learning. I'd like to get involved in what is going on with the language and its functionalities. Does anyone know any good blogs to read or podcasts to listen to?

Comment: I have a feeling your question will be marked inappropriate as per the site's guidelines, but to answer your question anyway--Swift is very new, best practices are yet to be established, and just about the best reference right now is [The Swift Programming Language](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11) and WWDC 2014 videos. Also checkout NSHipster and objc.io

Answer (score 0):

Take a [**quick swift tour**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html) and make your [**first app at 6 mins**](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=16)

Comment: After that you can start free Udacity Swift Course: https://www.udacity.com/course/ud585
And watching video tutorials on Ray Wenderlich's Blog: http://www.raywenderlich.com/video-tutorials
and Jameson Quave's Blog: http://jamesonquave.com/blog/tutorials/